# How To Update Database Value On Index.php Page After Editting On Edit.php Page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms, mysqli

**Index.php Page**
I am a beginner. 
This is index page in which i print a name of user who is logged in and i want to update the username whenever a user edit his detail i try to update it,it's updating the username but when i edit detail then i have log out first then login again then the name will update.I want to update the name instantly when a user edit his detail and redirect to index page just like facebook do.
i almost spend a week for solving this problem.Please give me code if anything needs to with ajax.
Thank you

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("inc/connection.php");
if (empty($_SESSION['usersession'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['msg'];
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WELCOME TO USER AREA</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <nav id="nav">
                <div class="logout">
                    WELCOME <?php echo $_SESSION['usersession']['name']; ?> // echo name of user
                    <a href="logout.php">Log out</a>        
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="edit.php">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a href="delete.php">Delete(not recommended)</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="para">
                some text
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit.php**
This is edit.php code

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['usersession'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
if (isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['msg'];
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>REGISTER HERE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="reg2">
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $id = $_SESSION['usersession']['id'];
                if (!empty($name && $email && $password)) {
                    if (!empty($password)) {
                        $password = sha1($password);
                        require_once("inc/connection.php");
                        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE register SET name='$name',email='$email',password='$password' WHERE id='$id'");
                        if ($query) {
                            header("Location: index.php");
                        } else {
                            echo "not updated right now please try again later";
                        }
                        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Your detail has been updated successfully";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "please put your updated password";
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="form">
            <form method="post" action="edit.php">
                <label>NAME</label><p>
                <input class="int" type="text" class="nm" name="name" placeholder="Please Enter Your Name Here" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usersession']['name']; ?>" /><p>
                    <label>EMAIL</label><p>
                <input class="int" type="email" class="em" name="email" placeholder="Please Enter Your Email Here" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usersession']['email']; ?>"  /><p>
                    <label>PASSWORD</label><p>
                    <input class="int" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Please Enter Your new Password Here" />
                <p></p>
                <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usersession']['id']; ?>"/>
                <input type="submit" name="btn" id="btu" value="Update">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your edit code never updates $_SESSION, so you'll always be displaying the old/original data. You are also vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: thanx for reply can you please tell me how can i solve this problem but i take care of sql_injection on login page .

Comment: `$_SESSION['whatever'] = $newvalue;` basically

Comment: $_SESSION['whatever'] = $newvalue; // on which page and how i apply this code, i am totally beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When updating your Database you didnt change the value in your $_SESSION.
You have to do that manually.

```
// Add that under $_SESSION['msg'] = '....'
$_SESSION['usersession']['username'] = $name; // Same with email and password
```

Note that your code is vulnerable to mysql-injection. You should [mysql_real_escape_string to avoid that.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Furthermore you display your message before even outputting your `<!DOCUMENT html>`. Please dont do that. Instead echo the message somewhere in your html!

Comment: if i do that on edit.php then how do i echo updated username on index.php

Comment: Your $_SESSION-Variable is shared across all pages (thats what sessions are for). So if you change it in your edit.php it will be changed when calling index.php, too

Comment: i did it like this is that you were talking about      if($query){
header("Location: index.php");
}else{
echo "not updated right now please try again later";
}
$_SESSION['msg']="Your detail has been updated successfully";
$_SESSION['usersession']['name']=$name;
}
}else{
echo "please put your updated password";
}

Comment: so what?? you cant set your header at this place because you got html-output already. Anyway - you can place my scriptline before using header, too

Comment: can you help me with one more thing that "how can i make my php strong(like expert) and how to can i understand oop in php",oop is also a topic which messed up my mind.

Comment: Through reading, trying and learning. Do your stuff and you will do better